# What exclamation mark means near the play test icon in front of class name. Espresso. Testing

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I write automated tests in Espresso for Android and i was faced with next problem.

I noitced the exclamation mark near the play icon in front of class name that we usually use for launch all tests of some class by one click.

Please take a look a picture: [image]

I have to note that i don't get any errors, all my UI tests launch without problem.

Did i miss something? 
Or that exclamation mark does not have any relation with testing?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see all the Android Studio "Gutter Icons" in preferences.

**Preferences > Editor > General > Gutter Icons** (Mac, Android Studio 3.3.2)

Comment: If it's not listed there, then it could be a plugin you've installed that's altering the behaviour of this icon. Have you changed your setup recently?